# Different types of downloads on Cyanogen OS Website

Tags: downloading, stock-rom

** This question is for Cyanogen OS and not Cyanogen Mod.

On [the Cyanogen OS download page](https://cyngn.com/support), for my device (YU Yuphoria), I see 3 different downloads for my device, i.e.

cm-12.1-YOG4PAS47N-lettuce-signed-fastboot-5d674b9b61.zip

cm-12.1-YOG4PAS47N-lettuce-signed-806afa8c62.zip

cm-12.1-YOG4PAS47N-lettuce-boot-debuggable-c915697c50.img

It is clear that the first one is the firmware which is to be flashed over fastboot, but I'm skeptical about the second & the third one..

What do the 2nd & the 3rd link provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Signed fastboot zips:** 
>   These contain the complete rom and can overwrite everything including your data partition. These cannot be flashed via recovery - extract their contents and **flash via fastboot**.
>
> **Signed zips:**
>   Normal, stock or TWRP **recovery flashable** zips that won't overwrite your data partition.
>
> **Boot-debuggable images:** (This is only for developers/testers)
>   These are **boot images** (kernels) that enable **adb root** and the developer menu options. To be flashed via fastboot. (e.g.fastboot flash boot cm-12.1-YOG4PAS47N-lettuce-boot-debuggable-c915697c50.img)

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/general/official-cm11s-roms-ota-updates-t2906746